# How to make recordset (categories and subcategories)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

`categories (id, categoryName)`,
`menu (id, menuname, category_id)`

I would like to display all categories, which have one or more records in the `menu`.
And after every `categoryName` to show 5 `menuname`.

Is it possibe, to do this in the one recordset?

Thank you!

These are my 2 recordsets:

```
$query = "select a.id, a.name from categories as a where a.id in (select count(*) from menu as b on b.category_id = a.id)";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['name'];
    $category_id = intval($row['id']);
    $query = "select menuname from menu where category_id = $category_id limit 0, 5";
    $resultmenu = mysql_query($query);
    while ($rowmenu = mysql_fetch_array($resultmenu)) {
        echo $rowmenu['menuname'];
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*And after every categoryName to show 5 menuname.*"?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, i'm not sure what is meant by "*And after every categoryName to show 5 menuname*".

But to show a list of all category/menu names in alphabetical order you could use the following:

```
SELECT      C.categoryName,
            M.menuname
FROM        categories C
INNER JOIN  menu M ON M.category_id = C.id
ORDER BY    C.categoryName,
            M.menuname
```

**Update**:

At the moment your first query will only be returning at best one row. The subquery is currently counting the number of `menu` rows and then this figure is being used to pull a row from the category table, which isn't what you want.

The following query joins onto the `menu` table to ensure that at least one item exists, and then groups by the `category` fields to ensure that each item is only returned once:

```
$query = "select a.id, a.name from categories as a inner join menu as b on b.category_id = a.id group by a.id, a.name"
```

**Update 2**

Ah sorry, I understand now. No I don't think it's possible to achieve what you want in a single query. Even if it were possible I wouldn't recommend it. Looking at your code, you only want to print the `categoryName` once for each set of menu items. If you were able to pull back the `categoryName` and `menuname` items in one result set like so:

```
| categoryName | menuname |
---------------------------
| category1    | menu1    |
| category1    | menu2    |
| category1    | menu3    |
| category2    | menu4    |
```

When iterating through the results you would need to manually check when the `categoryName` had changed in order to print it out once for that set of `menuname` items.

Comment: I think the OP meant that for each `category` there should be no more than 5 `menu`.